# HandlerNotFound at trigger aws lambda function

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a problem with deployed to AWS Lambda function. I create an trigger to SQS queue, when I have new message then my trigger (index.receiver) processing this message. So, here is my code:

index.ts

```
import receiver from "./sqs/receiver";

exports.receiver = receiver;
```

sqs/receiver.ts

```
const receiver: SQSHandler = async (event) => {
  //some logic
};

export default receiver;
```

After trigger this function, I see in AWS CloudWatch that nothing is working correctly and throw me this error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
    "errorMessage": "index.receiver is undefined or not exported",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.receiver is undefined or not exported",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
        "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
}
```

Here is also my project tree:

```
.serverless
node_modules
sqs
- receiver.ts
index.ts
package.json
serverless.yml
```

and serverless.yml

```
service: some-name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: eu-central-1
  apiGateway:
    minimumCompressionSize: 1024 # Enable gzip compression for responses > 1 KB
  environment:
    AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: 1
  # SQS Permission given
  iamManagedPolicies:
  - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSQSFullAccess'

functions:
  receiver:
    handler: index.receiver
    events:
      - sqs: <my-sqs-arn>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you checked in the AWS console what is actually deployed to your Lambda function? I guess you have to create a JS file (or multiple of them) that are then deployed to AWS. So might be a good idea to first check what serverless has actually deployed to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem. Problem was in this, that in my `serverless.yml` I point handler like this: `handler: index.receiver` but, when we use Typescript we should point it to `dist/index.receiver` because AWS can handle only JS files, we also need to remember about build project with this function before using `serverless deploy`.